# Java HttpSession can be changed in runtime?

Tags: java, multithreading, session, tomcat, request

I have 2 servers. 
Server A has a cron system, which given a trigger requirement, calls the Server B through a servlet

In server B, when receiving the server A's call, i store serveral informations on the HttpSession and then i start a new thread, so i could free server A.

I have found, thought logs, that in several cases, when the thread in Server B is reaching the HttpSession, the values that were set before are different. They are not null or blank, they have acctual values, but not the ones i put.

The server A fires like, 30 notifications each 5 minutes. This means i will have several concurrent threads.

Why is the HttpSession being overriden by another thread?

Comment: Why do you use the session in the first place? Why don't you just pass the information that the thread needs to the Runnable's constructor?

Comment: When a user logs in the system, we save his credentials in the http session.
When Server A fires a notification, it carries a authentication, so it act as a login. This is the info is that we register in the HttpSession.
However, in some cases i notice thas the user info has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Section 2.3.3.4 of the Servlet Specification v 3.0 says,

> If a thread created by the application uses the container-managed
>   objects, such as the request or response [or session] object, those objects
>   must be accessed only within the object’s life cycle [...].

`HttpSession` objects are certainly container-managed objects, but their life cycle is not clearly defined by the Servlet specification.  It seems plausible, however, to consider the life cycle to end when the session has been invalidated, whether explicitly or by time out, and no request belonging to that session is being serviced.  After that point, if you continue to access the session object then all bets are off.  In particular, the container is permitted to cache and re-use managed objects, including session objects.

If your server A does not participate in session tracking, then every request will be assigned to a new session, and each one's lifetime will be a single timeout period.  In this case, you could consider setting the [default] timeout long enough to ensure that sessions do not time out during the course of one computation (but see below).  If your server A *does* participate in session tracking, on the other hand, then the session object will be open for modification on each request.

Whether server A participates in session tracking or not, however, it is poor form for an application thread such as those you start manually to access container-managed objects.  It would be better all around to use a different mechanism to provide data to them.

Comment: Based on your answer, I questioned the programmer responsible for the current architecture about the need to store information in the session.
His response was basically that, "every request creates a new session. So there is no reuse of HttpSession elements"

However, investigations done after this post prove the opposite.

As you said, the session object is being reused.
When entering the servlet. I identify that the session is already populated.

Now I have this problem to solve.

thanks for your answer.
Grateful